# How to add administrators to GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm having trouble understanding how to add administrators to my app. Of course, as the creator of the app, my account is an administrator. To add another, I go to the Administration Console, and click on Permissions in the sidebar. There's no option on that page to add an admin, but it offers a link to the "new Permissions page." On that page, I can add another account as an owner, but when I log in as that account, my app isn't visible in the Administration Console, and that account fails the programmatic `users.is_current_user_admin()` test.

Is App Engine just being buggy, or am I missing something?

Comment: To clarify, I'm using the Google account API for in-app authentication, and allowing all users (not just those in my domain) to access the app.

Answer (score 1):

You have first visited the old appengine console's permission page (https://appengine.google.com/permissions). Google removed the add member functionality from this page.

When you clicked the "Try the new Permissions page.", It will redirect to new appengine console(https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-appid/permissions). In this page, You can add new members to your application with permission `is owner` or `Can edit` or `Can view`. Once you add a member, Google will send the invitation to the member. They need to accept it. You can view the status from the same page. If the member is not accepted the invitation yet, You can see the status as "**Invitation sent. Waiting for response.**"

Once they accept the invitation, Member can able to access your application.

Comment: Where does Google "send the invitation to the member"? I haven't received any emails on the second account, and I can access the "new" Administration Console, but the account isn't considered an administrator in-app. The first account's view of the Administration Console doesn't say anything about an invitation.

Comment: Are you able to see your second account in permission page ?

Comment: Yes, I can see both accounts in the permission page, regardless of which I'm signed in as.

Comment: What is the permission status for that ? is it "Is Owner" ?

Comment: Yes, both accounts are owners of the app.

Comment: Then you should able to access your application and `users.is_current_user_admin()` should allow to login. What is the error message you are getting ? And please make sure you are using second email address. Better try to access using incognito window to avoid multiple login.

Comment: I'm not getting any error message; `users.is_current_user_admin()` is simply returning `False`.

Comment: I suspect that the behavior I'm seeing may be a bug, and I've filed a report with Google.